# Should I quit my job because it's burning me out?

Tags: resignation, developer, burnout

I am full-stack developer for a company that I'm working for almost 2 years. I really like my job and the people that I'm working with, but from a few months I have this weird problem, that I have to work instead of colleague of mine / which I agreed on and I am compensated for, it sounds a bit complicated but mainly we can say that I'm working for 2 people /.

Unfortunately, this is really burning me out lately, and even with this much work, my bosses keep asking me if I can't handle even more work, even though I'm explaining that I'm already having too much.

Lately I even thing that the salary I'm getting for that is not enough, so I have 2 options :

1. Ask them to handle this and hire another person to do the job, which will lead to reducing my salary, but in that case I'll be more relaxed at work and will have more time to evolve my skills.
2. I believe that I have skills to find a new job and take the same salary or even more that I'm taking now, but something is stopping me. It's like I'm too committed to my job and I can't even imagine to leave it.

I know I might sound stupid, but just wanted to let everything out and see opinions of people who are not on my place and see this from different point of view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "that I have to work instead of colleague of mine / which I agreed on and I am compensated for, it sounds a bit complicated but mainly we can say that I'm working for 2 people /."  What is your exact agreement and with who is it? ( colleague, boss, both)

Comment: @sf02 with both of them, but mainly it's with my boss, because my colleague is just the 'face' in front of the people we're working with

Comment: So you, your boss, and the colleague agreed that you alone would do your colleague's work?  Even if your compensation was doubled, I don't know why you would agree to this arrangement.

Comment: yes, this was the reason why I agreed, but with that I never get a raise on my normal salary because I think they are considering that taking a double compensation is raising

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those nice questions with a fairly simple answer. If your job is burning you out, **yes**, you need to fix that. No job is worth a burn-out.

There's very little point in having a bunch of money if you spend all your days stuck in bed because you can't get out anymore. There's even less point in having a bunch of money only to give all of it to the hospital. (Depending on where you live, all the money you made might not even be enough to pay those bills)

If you fear for your health, *change the situation you are in*. That means talking to your managers first if you like your job, but if they are not open to the idea for whatever reason **start looking for something else**.

Comment: You've explained it very well :) thanks, I'll certainly will think about it

Answer (score 5):

You've not really stated why your co-worker is unable to work efficiently.

However, you need to let your manager know that you don't have the bandwidth to continue this situation - sooner or later **all** of your work (not just the extra tasks) is going to suffer for it and reduce your overall productivity.

You need to let your manager know that you need help - either by recruiting someone else,  asking someone else to share the extra work, or addressing why your co-worker is unable to fulfil their duty.

The only other alternative is to consider seeking employment elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is that my manager is obviously not a good one, because when I'm telling him I have too much stuff to do, he just offers me to do more instead of actually send me some help, so that's why I think this getting out of situation might be seeking for another job..

Comment: Why "let the manager" know anything?  (1) do work (2) take money (3) go home.

Comment: @Fattie if help is needed, who is the OP supposed to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a "to-do" list of all the things you need to do, and what their priorities are.

When you're given any new work by your manager, make a point of asking them what work should be de-prioritised to make way for their new work.  Eventually, they may realise that every time they give you something new to do, it just makes their previous jobs later.

Meanwhile, just plod through your prioritised to-do list.  If something happens later than someone wanted it to, that's tough.

Comment: Worst thing is that my manager actually doesn't gives me the task, but I directly communicate with my clients from mine and my colleagues name, which makes everything even harder to manage. Luckily for now we didn't had any issue with the time management of the tasks, so the clients are happy.

Answer (score -7):

OP has clarified that:

> "I don't really want to return to old salary, only the workload"

This is achieved extremely simply.

1. Return to your old workload.

End of story.

When you are asked to estimate how long something will take, do so accurately.

If someone complains that you are going slowly or you should work more hours, politely say you're going as fast as possible, and say nothing else.

**Please note that** your point one in the question is **very wrong**...

Don't tell them to do anything, and keep out of your mind what they do or don't have to, should, or can do. It's none of your business. Work 7.5 hour days, take the money, and go home.

What to do next:

2. Click to stackoverflow jobs and find a new job. Two years is a LONG, LONG time to work one place as a programmer if you're starting out, time to move on.

Setting aside the question and looking at the whole situation: change jobs immediately.

It's the only way in the business to drastically move your salary ahead.

Comment: Why suggest that they lower the salary? He is already suggesting not being compensated enough.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I believe OP should just move along to make more money.  But I believe what  he is asking is "how to go back to the old salary/workload".

Comment: Why is two years a long time to be at one place as a developer?

Comment: Hi @Fattie I don't really want to return to old salary, only the workload... The reason my salary is not getting higher is because they think that working for the second person and getting compensated for it is enough 'raise', but really it isn't because I'm just doing a job for 2 salaries, or do I see it in wrong way ? Maybe you are right and it's time to search a new job..

Comment: Hi @cela  of course, everything that people commonly say (like "save for retirement" or "don't lie" or whatever) can only be an opinion.   But it's a basic in the software industry that the only way to "get ahead" from one's first job is to move on to another company.

Comment: hi @mch  ... sigh, fine I will edit my answer!